# How to check vector elements are in same order or not

Tags: r

I want to check my vectors are in same order or not. Especially last two elements.

```
x<- c(0.817104, 0.241665, 0.040581, 0.022903, 0.019478, 0.019846)

isTRUE(all.equal(tail(x,2)[1],tail(x,2)[2]))
```

# [1] FALSE

But you can see that they are in same order (10^-2). Why I'm getting `FALSE`

Comment: You are checking if they are equal, not in the same order

Comment: rather use `is.unsorted(all.ex)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus ok what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Alexander my typos! `is.unsorted(x)`

Comment: @SIslam actually I am not looking for that. I actually look for if the last two value is in the same order return `TRUE` value.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be a shorter way, but I have this idea: take the last two elements and multiply them by 10 until you get a >1 number (I'm supposing all your entries <1). Something like this: I x is your vector

```
n1 = x[-1] #the last one
n2 = x[-2] #the other

counter1 = 0
while (n1 <=1){
    n1 = n1*10
    counter1 = counter1 +1
   }
```

Then you do the same with n2, using a counter2 variable. Finally get `counter1==counter2`